# Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using google services at the very first time in my app(ionic platform). I am following this [doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start). While building my app, I got the following error message. Please help out. Thank you.

A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Answer (score 12):

Please add the plugin to your project by updating your top-level `build.gradle` and your app-level `build.gradle` files as follows:

> 1. Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

> 2. Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

More information regarding this can be found in [GCM - Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).

And, in addition to that, the guide or workaround given in GitHub - [GCMPushPlugin](https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin/issues/2) might also help.

Comment: Thank you Teyam. After I made the changes, I got the following error. Please help me. Thank you.

Error: /-/-/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit cod e 1 Error output: /-/-/platforms/android/src/com/gonzaloaune/cordova/gcm/GPPRegistrat ionIntentService.java:40: error: cannot find symbol GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null); ^ symbol: variable INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE location: class GoogleCloudMessaging

Comment: you probably need to add more of your build.gradle file to help address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add   classpath com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0  dependencies at project level build.gradle

Refer the sample block from project level build.gradle

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```